# Pasting from google docs removes the styles

Tags: 7, wysiwyg

When I copy text from a google doc and paste it to the ckeditor using the paste from word button it removes all the styling (bold, italics, ...).
How can I fix that?

**update**
*Steps to reproduce* :
Copy one word from a google doc that is both underlined and italicized
    Paste it into editor
*Expected result* :
The word is pasted in italicized and underlined.
*Actual result*:
The word is bolded, no underlines or italics to be found.

Comment: Are you using Full HTML as your text format?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about a [known bug in ckeditor](https://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/13877), and not related to Drupal

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what Google docs formatting code is like, it's possibly just HTML. If it is HTML you should be able to directly paste into CKeditor which should paste the formatting.

If you don't get the formatting as you expect and if you don't know how to format in HTML/CSS you have 2 options:

You can try paste into Microsoft Word and then use the "paste from word" button, but not sure if it will keep or remove the formatting, just worth a try.

Alternatively, sometimes it's best to paste plain text and do the formatting in the CKeditor. I know it can be time consuming if it's a lot of text.

Comment: Using that button is like pasting plain text (no styling). I want to keep the formating from my GDoc.

Comment: I just read the question again and realised my answer is not right. Have you tried pasting normally, without using 'paste from word' button?

Comment: directly pasting bold everything.

Comment: I've edited my answer with the only 2 options I can think of. Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks, the first option works. But it is not ideal. I came across : https://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/13877 which is th pb I am having.